# Перегрузка операторов + - * в шаблонном классе

Tags: c++, классы, шаблоны-с++, перегрузка-операторов

Пишу шаблонный класс матрицы, не могу понять как тут правильно реализовать перегрузку операторов

```
class Matrix
{
private:
    T** data; 
public:
    Matrix(int rows, int columns);
    ~Matrix();
    Matrix<T>& multiply(int x);
    Matrix<T> add(Matrix<T> m);
    Matrix<T> sub(Matrix<T> m);
    Matrix<T> operator+(const Matrix<T> m) const;
    Matrix<T> operator-(const Matrix<T> m) const;
    Matrix<T> operator*(const Matrix<T> m) const;
    Matrix<T>& operator=(const Matrix<T>& m) const;
};

template <class T> Matrix<T> operator+(const Matrix<T> &m1) const {
    return *this->add(m1);
}
```

Компилятор выдает ошибку на строках реализации operator+
`error C2270: +: модификаторы недопустимы для функций, не являющихся членами`

Comment: Вы пишете этот класс для тренировки, или нет? Если нет, лучше замените `T** data` на одномерный `std::vector`, или хотя бы на `std::unique_ptr`, и уберите деструктор. А если да, то перед тем, как ударяться в перегрузку операторов, нужно в дополнение к деструктору написать копирующий конструктор и оператор присваивания (и, если можете, перемещающий конструктор и оператор присваивания). Без них вашим классом нельзя нормально пользоваться, и в т.ч. нельзя нормально перегрузить эти операторы.

Answer (score 2):

У вас пара неприятностей:

Вы забыли указать при определении оператора, что это член класса:

```
template <class T> 
Matrix<T> Matrix<T>::operator+(const Matrix<T> &m1) const {
    return *this->add(m1);
}
```

Ну и вторая — у вас оператор в определении отличается от оператора в объявлении, в котором вы почему-то передаете **не** ссылку. Добавьте `&` в

```
Matrix<T> operator+(const Matrix<T>& m) const;
```

Comment: Я дописал конструктор копирования и оператор присваивания по совету из комментария выше, но теперь выдает ошибку error C2662: Matrix<T>::add: невозможно преобразовать указатель "this" из "const Matrix<T>" в "Matrix<T> &"

Comment: Соответственно измените и `add`, чтоб принимала константную ссылку. Зачем вы вообще в функции передаете *копии* матрицы?